# How do I retrieve the value from a textbox in this example below

Tags: php, mysql

In my code below I am trying to INSERT VALUES into a database. I am using a switch statement where if a textbox equals one of the cases, then it matchs with one of the ‘OptionType’ rows in the database and from that display the ‘OptionId’ which matches the ‘OptionType’.

The problem though is that while doing a var_dump on the $optionquery, it shows that it is not retireving the value from the textbox. How can I get $selected_option from the query to retrieve the value from the textbox ($_POST[‘gridValues’])?

At the moment I am trying to use the case statement to retrieve the values from the textbox. E.g. If the textbox contains the number '4', then case '4' should be triggered.

Now below is the code of the textbox which is appended into a new table row in the application:

```
     <script>

            function insertQuestion(form) { 

  var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');  

            var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
            var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
            var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");
            var $questionType = '';

            $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

             var $this = $(this);
             var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                             .attr('value',$this.val())

            $options.append($optionsText);
            $questionType = $this.val();

            });

    $tr.append($options);
    $tbody.append($tr); 

        </script>


        <form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >

        <table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
        <tr class="option">
        <td>Option Type:</td>
        <td>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </form>
```

Below is the php code where all the database stuff happens:

```
$insertquestion = array();


$options = $_POST['gridValues'];

switch ($options){

    case "3": 
    $selected_option = "A-C";
    break;

    case "4": 
    $selected_option = "A-D";
    break;

    case "5": 
    $selected_option = "A-E";
    break;

    default:
    $selected_option = "";
    break;

}      

$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '" 
     . mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";

$optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
$optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs);
$optionid = $optionrecord['OptionId'];



foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question)
{
    $insertquestion[] ="' ".  mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid ) . "'";
}

  $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (OptionId) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";



echo($questionsql);

var_dump($optionquery);

mysql_close();
```

Comment: what does `context` contains in your call of `$('.gridTxt', context)` ?

Comment: I included the context code in the update but context is the name of the table which is (#optionAndAnswer).

Comment: So when you var_dump($_POST), you are seeing the 'gridValues' key in there?

Comment: Also, how is this form being submitted? I see no button or input with a type='submit' and I don't see any ajax going on.

Comment: I havn't included the submit button but there is a submit button and there is ajax coding. The php coding you see that does the database stuff is on a seperate page which it goes to. If the default in the case statement was lets say the 'A-C', then it works perfectly so the query does work, but obviously I want it to recieve the values from the textbox not from a default state.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte When I do a var_dump($_POST) it shows this: ["gridValues"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "3" }. The above var_dump was for two questions and both question's had the number '3' in the textbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop around your switch (based on your var_dump):

```
$option_array = array();
foreach( $options as $i )
{
  switch( $i )
  {
    case '1':
    if( !empty( $i ) ){ $option_array[] = $selected_option; }
    break;
    //so on, and so forth for all of your field data...
  }
}
```

Now that you have all of your field values re-worked and stored in the $option_array, you can loop through:

```
foreach( $option_array as $i )
{
   //do whatever mysql jazz you need to do to get your data
}
```

Comment: Hi, this has retireved the optionId's from the text box. I have one little problem though. If I add two questions, first question is suppose to be 'O3' and second question 'O12', what it does instead in the INSERT VALUES is that both questions has an optionId of 'O12'. Is it because I need to change the loop for the $insertquestion[]?

Comment: Okay yeah you are overwriting $selected_options. See my modified answer